# Model driven forms using angular2 RC2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

After updating to the new angular2 RC2, I tried following the docs I found online to recreate a model driven form, below is the code

COMPONENT.ts

```
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

myForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormGroup({
     first: new FormControl(),
     last: new FormControl()
  })
});
```

This is the HTML code

```
<form formGroup="myForm"  >
   <div formGroupName="name">
     <input formControlName ="first" >
     <input formControlName ="last" >
  </div>
</form>
```

But on runtime, I get this error,

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
No provider for NgControl ("
<form formGroup="myForm"  >
  <div formGroupName="name">
     [ERROR ->]<input formControlName ="first" >
     <input formControlName ="last" >
  </div>
"): ProductComponent@9:5
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error.

P.S The new template driven forms work, just not model driven
P.S I am using Angular2-seed project by mgechev

Comment: you need to add ngModel to your inputs....  `<input formControlName="first" ngModel>`  This is how it knows to generate the control to inject.  You can do the binding as well `[(ngModel)]="myProperty"` if you need it.

This may change in the near future so I don't want to make it an answer.

Comment: Hi @JacobRobert, I tried adding ngModel to the input, but I still get the same error 
`[ERROR ->]<input formControlName="first" ngModel>`. I really dont know what I am doing wrong, do you think you can show me a working example on plunkr so I can see whats wrong or something 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had same error after updating to rc2. In main.ts I changed this line
`import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms/index';`
to
`import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following might help:

Add new forms to packages.json file.

```
"@angular/forms": "0.1.0",
```

Disable deprecated forms and enable new forms in main file:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
  ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Your app component import directives (FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES) from new forms. Note that ngFormModel is now formGroup and ngControl is now formControlName.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [],
    template: `
        <div>
          <form [formGroup]="form">
                 <input [formControlName]="first">
                 <input [formControlName]="last">
          </form>
        </div>
      `,
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class App {
    public form: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {

        this.form = fb.group({
            first: ["", Validators.required],
            last: ["", Validators.required]
        });
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.